# How to capture the result of stored procedure through shell script?

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, plsql

I'm trying to execute stored procedure through shell script and try to get return from stored procedure but I didn't get any thing from the stored procedure on other hand same thing I do with sqlplus prompt and I'm able to get the result

```
sqlplus -silent xxx@xxx <<EOF
set serveroutput on
declare

DE_REC_COUNT number(10);
begin
    DE_DUP_PROC ('T_MCL_30404_20150317_020','MCL','30404','FT',DE_REC_COUNT);

end;

EOF
```

Through sqlplus prompt

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
declare

DE_REC_COUNT number;
begin
    DE_DUP_PROC ('T_MCL_30404_20150317_020','MCL','30404','FT',DE_REC_COUNT);

end;  

0

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Did the `-silent` apply to the sqlplus prompt?

Comment: thanks for the reply yes we can use -silent with sqlplus.

Comment: Is the zero coming from a `dbms_output` call inside the procedure? Are you trying to capture that into a variable? Or the value of `DE_REC_COUNT`, if that is different? Also niehter command will run as you don't have a `/` after the anonymous blocks. Is this really exactly what you are running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of the anonymous block in the shell script will not be executed as shown, because you don't have [a slash after the block to run it](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#i1039663). If you run that you get no output at all. If you change it to have a slash:

```
sqlplus -silent xxx@xxx <<EOF
set serveroutput on
declare
  DE_REC_COUNT number(10);
begin
    DE_DUP_PROC ('T_MCL_30404_20150317_020','MCL','30404','FT',DE_REC_COUNT);
end;
/
EOF
```

then you'll see:

```
0

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

You've shown the interactive version in SQL*Plus without the slash too, but you must have had that to see the output you showed.

If you want the zero - which seems to be coming from a `dbms_output` call in your procedure, rather than directly from your anonymous block - n a shell variable you can refer to later, you can assign the output of the heredoc to a variable:

```
MY_VAR=`sqlplus -silent xxx@xxx <<EOF
set serveroutput on
set feedback off
declare

DE_REC_COUNT number(10);
begin
    DE_DUP_PROC ('T_MCL_30404_20150317_020','MCL','30404','FT',DE_REC_COUNT);
end;
/

EOF`

printf "Got back MY_VAR as %s\n" ${MY_VAR}
```

Note that I've added `set feedback off` so you don't see the `PL/SQL procedure successfully completed` line. Now when you run that you'll see:

```
Got back MY_VAR as 0
```

and you can do whatever you need to with `${MY_VAR}`. It depends what you mean by 'capture' though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how it can be done by surrounding the code with the evaluation operators (` back quotes):

```
#!/bin/sh
results=`sqlplus -s xxx@xxx <<EOF
set serveroutput on feedback off
declare

DE_REC_COUNT number(10);
begin
    DE_DUP_PROC ('T_MCL_30404_20150317_020','MCL','30404','FT',DE_REC_COUNT);

end;
/
EOF`

echo $results
```

Comment: FYI - If your shell supports it, using the newer `$(...)` construct around the command instead of backquotes for command substitution is preferred as that construct is easier to read, handles nesting much easier, etc.  http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst

Answer (score 0):

Lets say for instance I have a below procedure which calculates the sum of two numbers and prints the total using **dbms_output.put_line()** method

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE SUM
  (
    a IN NUMBER,
    b IN NUMBER)
AS
  total NUMBER;
BEGIN
  total:= a + b;
  dbms_output.put_line(total);
END;
```

Then in order to call this in our shell script we need to call this procedure in an anonymous block and store in a variable, later using echo we can execute the command.

```
plsqlcode=`sqlplus -silent hr/sandeep@orcl <<EOF
set serveroutput on
begin
sum(10,20);
end;
/
EOF`

echo $plsqlcode
```

Ideally this is not a recommended approach you should keep your shell and pl/sql code in separate files.