# Unix: issue with out parameter of procedure

Tags: unix, ksh

I have written a plsql procedure which has 2 in parameters and 1 out parameter. I am calling this procedure in unix(ksh) but it is just reading the out parameter if I print it. I tried to compare the out parameter in "if" condition but it failed. I have written it in following way.

```
var v_test number;
exec procedurename (1,2,:v_test);

print v_test; ---this prints the value as 1 which is return by procedure

if [$v_test -eq 1]
then
Print"success";
Else
Print"try again"
End if;
```

But while comparing v_test with 1, it gets empty value for v_test1.. and compares empty with 1 and gives error. . Can anybody help me with it?

Comment: Please consider making a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE) to allow us to replicate the conditions that are causing you this problem. (Sometimes, just creating the MCVE is enough to show you where the problem is!)

Answer (score -1):

try looking at the answers to this question as I think its what you are looking for

[How to capture the result of stored procedure through shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32055863/how-to-capture-the-result-of-stored-procedure-through-shell-script)

Comment: Rick, thanks for your answer, and welcome to StackOverflow! If you think this question is a duplicate of another one, the best way to handle it would be to "flag" it using the link under the question, and follow the prompts to mark it as a duplicate.